# How to avoid separate while loops when re-prompting a user?

Tags: python, loops, input, prompt

I was writing a basic program in python to prompt user for their height and weight. If they enter a negative number I want it to loop until they enter a value that is positive. I wanted to know if this code could be improved upon:

```
while True:
    height = eval(input("Please enter your height in inches: "))
    if height > 0:
        break
    elif height <= 0:
        print("Invalid entry.")

while True:
    weight = eval(input("Enter your weight in pounds: "))
    if weight > 0:
        break
    elif weight <= 0:
        print("Invalid entry.")
```

I tried combining it into one while loop but I think the if/elif statements start to become an issue. Does anyone have advice to make this cleaner?

Comment: You could write a function that prompts in a loop, and call it from both places.

Comment: Don't use `eval(input())`. Use `int(input())`

Comment: `elif height <= 0:` should just be `else:`.

Comment: @barman not need else